# Razor void function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have Razor function which outputs some data and as result does not return anything (that's a long story why it is done this way):

```
@functions
{
  public static void SampleHelperMethod()
  {
    //...
  }
}
```

How can I call it in view now? I tried `@MyFunctions.SampleHelperMethod()` but it doesn't work for void functions.

Comment: It seems extremely odd to put logic in a view.  What exactly is the function doing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Declaration**

```
@functions
{
    public static void TestFunction()
    {

    }
}
```

**Use in View**

```
@{ TestFunction(); }
```

Because this is a function that does not return anything, you need to wrap it in the braces like you would and if/for statement.  However, like Erik said, it is really unclear why this logic would be declared in the view...you may consider creating a helpers class that your views can include.  This will allow for reuse and better separations of concerns.